# PyQt alarm clock: best practice for triggering alarm

Tags: python-2.7, time, qt4, pyqt4

I am programming a pyqt alarm clock that I would like to run in the background on my system, and show a popup whenever the specified time is met. My question is what would be the best way to handle the alarm triggering itself? I could use a QTimer but that seems really messy. Or I could have a function run every minute to check if any of my alarms match the current time (like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqK8N48kPXs)), but that seems wasteful considering I don't really need to check EVERY minute of the day if I don't have to, and it is less accurate.

I can post a code snippet if needed (I have the GUI built) but I don't think it's necessary. I don't need anyone to write my program for me, just point me in the right direction! I'm guessing there is some great Qt function for this already that I just don't know about yet (there always seems to be something...)

Comment: whats your os? python version? pyqt version? tag them.

Comment: Thanks, updated tags. Os is Windows 7 but that shouldn't matter with PyQt right?

Comment: An alarm requires a ticking clock, which in qt means you must use one of its timer mechanisms. This in turn requires calling a function with a frequency that is equal to the smallest unit of time you wish to measure. So an alarm with one second accuracy must call that function every second. The function should simply check a list of date-times to see if any alarms should be triggered at that moment. You will need to use a single-application local server and run it in the background.

Comment: @ekhumoro Ok, makes sense. I was just checking to see if there was anything else, my OCD for optimization sometimes leads me into dead ends...